# How to set Date field to Null or Blank using flows?

Tags: visual-workflow, date

I am trying to set a date field to Null when there is a checkbox set for a record.

I have tried using Formula field of type Date and setting it to Null, using process builder global constant and tried to set it to null, used custom labels as well but to no avail.
None of the methods I have used seems to set the date field to NULL or Blank

PFA
1)Flow design

[image]

2)Flow node
[image]

3)When I tried to run it in debug mode it is showing as Null
[image]

4)When I go back to the record the date field is not blank but gets filled with any arbitrary value,however this is to also add,the moment I replace the blank or Null with a Now() or Date.today() it correctly displays todays date in the field.

P.S. this is to also add that it is a Date type field.

Comment: What does your flow look like? A screenshot could help us help you better.

Comment: hi @sfdcfox added the screenshots

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a formula field - simply leaving the value entry blank in the Assignment element will set the null.  In the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_feature_variable.htm&type=5):

> If you leave a field or resource value blank, the value is null at run
> time

Comment: +1 though the reason I asked the question is it feels more like a "they forgot to save their changes" rather than using an incorrect input value. We'll see how it turns out.

Comment: Hello @sfdcfox and David I have added my comments provided s.s for the flow.Could you please have a look

Comment: This is not a solution. I am currently using this solution and to no avail it is not working.